# How to fix this error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Window'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I got this issue when I send data to backend which means I collect name, description, price and categories from User. It's working fine but the user click dropdown of paid option and select any option on their its came this error please check it out my code.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import InstructorRoute from "../../../components/routes/InstructorRoute";
import { Button, ButtonGroup, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import CourseCreateForm from "../../../components/forms/CourseCreateForm";
import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

// const { Option } = Select;

const createCourse = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  // state
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    price: "",
    uploading: false,
    paid: true,
    loading: false,
  });

  const [image, setImage] = useState({});
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState("");
  const [uploadButtonText, setUploadButtonText] = useState("Upload Image");;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleImage = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    setUploadButtonText(file.name);
    setValues({ ...values, loading: true });

    // resize
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 720, 500, "JPEG", 100, 0, async (uri) => {
      try {
        let { data } = await axios.post("/api/course/upload-image", {
          image: uri,
        });
        console.log("IMAGE UPLOADED", data);
        // set image in the state
        setImage(data);
        setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
        toast("Image upload failed. Try later.");
      }
    });
  };

  const handleImageRemove = async () => {
    try {
      // console.log(values);
      setValues({ ...values, loading: true });
      const res = await axios.post("/api/course/remove-image", { image });
      setImage({});
      setPreview("");
      setUploadButtonText("Upload Image");
      setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
      toast("Image upload failed. Try later.");
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(values);
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/course", {
        ...values,
        image,
      });
      toast.success("Great! Now you can start adding lessons");
      router.push("/creator");
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err.response.data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <InstructorRoute>
      <h1 className=" text-center square">Create Course</h1>
      <div className="pt-3 pb-3">
        <CourseCreateForm
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          handleImage={handleImage}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          values={values}
          setValues={setValues}
          preview={preview}
          uploadButtonText={uploadButtonText}
          handleImageRemove={handleImageRemove}
        />
      </div>
      <pre style={{color:"white"}}>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)}</pre>
    </InstructorRoute>
  );
};

export default createCourse;
```

I send data via props createCourse to CourseCreateForm

```
import { Button, ButtonGroup, IconButton, Badge } from "@material-ui/core";
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';

// const { Option } = Select;

const CourseCreateForm = ({
    handleSubmit,
    handleImage,
    handleChange,
    values,
    setValues,
    preview,
    uploadButtonText,
    handleImageRemove,
}) => {
    // const children = [];
    // for (let i = 9.99; i <= 100.99; i++) {
    //     children.push(<Select key={i.toFixed(2)}>${i.toFixed(2)}</Select>);
    // }
    return (
        <>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="container" style={{
                padding: "30px",
                color: "#fff",
                // margin: "-54px 23px",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.06)",
                border: "1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
                width: "100%",
                borderRadius: "15px",
                // padding: "32px",
                backdropFilter: "blur(10px)",
                // position: "absolute",
                // right: "0px",
                // width: "300px",
                /* border: 3px solid #73AD21; */
                // padding: "10px",
            }}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        value={values.name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <textarea
                        name="description"
                        cols="7"
                        rows="7"
                        value={values.description}
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    ></textarea>
                </div>

                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Select
                                color="secondary"
                                style={{ width: "100%", color: "white" }}
                                // size="large"
                                value={values.paid}
                                onChange={(v) => setValues({ ...values, paid: !values.paid })}
                            >

                                <MenuItem value={true}>Paid</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={false}>Free</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {values.paid && (
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Select
                                defaultValue="$9.99"
                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                onChange={(v) => setValues({ ...values, price: v })}
                                // tokenSeparators={[,]}
                                size="large"

                            >

                                <MenuItem >100</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem >200</MenuItem>


                            </Select>


                            {/* <input
                                type="number"
                                name="Price"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter Price"
                                onChange={(v) => setValues({ ...values, price:v })}
                            /> */}


                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="category"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Category"
                        value={values.category}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>


                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block text-left">
                                {uploadButtonText}
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    name="image"
                                    onChange={handleImage}
                                    accept="image/*"
                                    hidden
                                />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {preview && (
                        <Badge badgeContent={"X"} onClick={handleImageRemove} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} color="error">
                            <Avatar width={200} src={preview} />
                        </Badge>
                    )}

                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <Button
                            onClick={handleSubmit}
                            disabled={values.loading || values.uploading}
                            loading={values.loading}
                            size="large"
                            shape="round"
                            color="secondary"
                            variant="contained"
                        >
                            {values.loading ? "Saving..." : "Save & Continue"}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
    );

};

export default CourseCreateForm;
```

This is an output of the code and I specified the dropdown in red mark.

[image]

This the error actually came.

[image]

Comment: The error means the object you pass to `JSON.stringify` has a circular reference. Try logging `values` to the console to check where the circular reference is.

Comment: @juliomalves [link]https://prnt.sc/1rgkxik this is the value i got in a console. in this case i put the value in price means i gotta that error